# WPF TreeView leaking the selected item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory, memory-leaks

I currently have a strange memory leak with WPF TreeView. When I select an item in the TreeView, the corresponding bound ViewModel is strongely hold in the TreeView EffectiveValueEntry[] collection. The issue is that it is not released when the ViewModel is removed from it's parent collection.

Here is a simple code to reproduce the issue :

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace TreeViewMemoryLeak
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Entry> Entries
        {
            get
            {
                if (entries == null)
                {
                    entries = new ObservableCollection<Entry>() { new Entry() { DisplayName = "First Entry" } };
                }
                return entries;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { entries.Clear(); }

        private ObservableCollection<Entry> entries;

    }

    public class Entry : DependencyObject
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewMemoryLeak.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewMemoryLeak"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="250">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Entry}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="delete item" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
        <TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**To reproduce the issue**

Select the item, then click the button to clear the ObservableCollection. Now check the EffectiveValueEntry[] on the TreeView control : the ViewModel is still there and is not flagged for garbage collection.

Comment: What .Net Version are you using?

Comment: I have the issue with .NET 3.5 and 4.0. I totally forgot to mention it, sorry. I'll test with 4.5 right now.

Comment: Issue still present with .NET 4.5

Comment: I have the same issue with the TreeView. I have posted a bug entry at **Microsoft Connect**: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778557/wpf-treeview-memory-leak-net-4-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I finally came up with a rather violent solution. I remove the reference from the EffectiveValues collection myself when deleting the last object in the TreeView. It may be overkill but at least, it works.

```
public class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override void OnSelectedItemChanged(RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        base.OnSelectedItemChanged(e);

        if (Items.Count == 0)
        {
            var lastObjectDeleted = e.OldValue;
            if (lastObjectDeleted != null)
            {
                var effectiveValues = EffectiveValuesGetMethod.Invoke(this, null) as Array;
                if (effectiveValues == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

                bool foundEntry = false;
                int index = 0;
                foreach (var effectiveValueEntry in effectiveValues)
                {
                    var value = EffectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod.Invoke(effectiveValueEntry, null);
                    if (value == lastObjectDeleted)
                    {
                        foundEntry = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    index++;
                }

                if (foundEntry)
                {
                    effectiveValues.SetValue(null, index);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected MethodInfo EffectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod
    {
        get
        {
            if (effectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod == null)
            {
                var effectiveValueEntryType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Where(t => t.Name == "EffectiveValueEntry").FirstOrDefault();
                if (effectiveValueEntryType == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

                var effectiveValueEntryValuePropertyInfo = effectiveValueEntryType.GetProperty("Value", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (effectiveValueEntryValuePropertyInfo == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

                effectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod = effectiveValueEntryValuePropertyInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
                if (effectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

            }
            return effectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod;
        }
    }

    protected MethodInfo EffectiveValuesGetMethod
    {
        get
        {
            if (effectiveValuesGetMethod == null)
            {
                var dependencyObjectType = typeof(DependencyObject);
                var effectiveValuesPropertyInfo = dependencyObjectType.GetProperty("EffectiveValues", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (effectiveValuesPropertyInfo == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

                effectiveValuesGetMethod = effectiveValuesPropertyInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
                if (effectiveValuesGetMethod == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            return effectiveValuesGetMethod;
        }
    }

    #region Private fields
    private MethodInfo effectiveValueEntryValueGetMethod;
    private MethodInfo effectiveValuesGetMethod;
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: We found that at `effectiveValues[index + 1]` there was a `BindingExpression` which also referenced `lastObjectDeleted` (i.e `((BindingExpression)value).ParentBinding.Source == lastObjectDeleted`), so we deleted that too.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you binded your treeview with [`OneTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx) mode, so your collection was 'snapshotted'. As stated:

**UPDATED:**

`EffectiveValueEntry` is about how `DependencyObjects` store the values of their `DependencyProperties`. This collection will hold object as long as treeView has selected item. As soon as you select something else collection will be updated.

Comment: Actually, the "OneTime" binding was a failed attempt at resolving the issue I found on another thread. Removing it does not change anything and it's not the cause of the issue. EDIT: I'll try the OneWay binding to see if the issue is solved. EDIT2: Does not work, Entry still alive.

Comment: Yes it's about dependency propertie storage. It's just annoying that memory is not released when the last object is removed if it was selected. In this case, I have no more objects in the treeView, and the object will be hold until the application is closed. Anyway thank you for your answer, I can't solve my issue, but at least, you confirmed what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it using one of the solutions on this [`link`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d5220101-e164-407f-ba02-64b0233e1647/) (posted by Tom Goff). Do the following:

```
ClearSelection(this.treeView);
this.treeView.SelectedValuePath = ".";
this.treeView.ClearValue(TreeView.SelectedValuePathProperty);
this.treeView.ItemsSource = null;
```

...

```
public static void ClearSelection(TreeView treeView)
{
    if (treeView != null)
        ClearSelection(treeView.Items, treeView.ItemContainerGenerator);
}

private static void ClearSelection(ItemCollection collection, ItemContainerGenerator generator)
{
    if ((collection != null) && (generator != null))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            TreeViewItem treeViewItem = generator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as TreeViewItem;
            if (treeViewItem != null)
            {
                ClearSelection(treeViewItem.Items, treeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator);
                treeViewItem.IsSelected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```